# Simple PHP string check not working

Tags: javascript, php, string, if-statement

I hate to even post this question, but I can't seem to get this to work for me. I can echo `$the_page` directly before the `if` statement, but yet the `if` statement always comes up "`else`". Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
<?php if(is_page('sp')){$the_page = 1;} else { };

if($the_page === 1) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#form-interest option:first:contains('---')").html('Área De Interés*:');
        });
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#form-interest option:first:contains('---')").html('Area of Interest*:');
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT:**
Using some of your thoughts, I cleaned this up to something cleaner. the is_page() is a Wordpress call and with this revised version I am getting the Spanish "Ir al Inicio" printing correctly (so the is_page function must be working), but $interest does not print "Área De Interés*:" as it should. The `else` is outputing both the text and the `$interest` string correctly.

```
<?php if(is_page('sp')) { $interest = 'Área De Interés*:'; ?>
    Ir al Inicio
<?php } else { $interest = 'Area of Interest*:'; ?>
    SCROLL TO TOP
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var interest = '<?php echo $interest; ?>';
        $("#form-interest option:first:contains('---')").html(interest);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more? Like the is_page function etc? Also, you should set $the_page = 0; in the first else. Othervise you could just check if $the_page is actually set, as you are not setting it if the page is not 'sp'.

Comment: `if always else`...which one, you have 2 of them? Also save duplicating code by simply switching the message that goes into the html

Comment: How did you determine that you can echo `$the_page`? Did you use `var_dump()` to make sure of its contents?

Comment: Also, what is this code doing? If you're doing localisation, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Jack, I am trying to replace the wording in a dropdown form depending which language the page is in.

Comment: For me both of your versions work correctly when I replace the `is_page` function with `true`. Are we seeing your complete code?

Comment: @joshofsorts why not just  `echo($interest)`

Comment: `$interest` is a string so you don't need `json_encode()` unless I am missing something. you should do `echo $interest;`

Comment: @Marvin with the last code I posted the response I am getting is uneven. If I am on the "sp" page, the footer will include the proper Spanish from the `if/else` statement ("Ir al Inicio"), but will not include the `$interest` string. If I am on the English page (the `else`), I see both the English from the `if/else` statement ("SCROLL TO TOP") and the output of the `$interest` string ("Area of Interest*:"). Not sure why one would work, but the other doesn't? If I put `echo $interest` immediately after `$interest = "Área De Interés*:"`, it outputs the string correctly. Headscratcher.

Comment: @JFK you are right, I made the correction, still getting the same response as notated in my comment above. Here are the two pages for reference, code effects the footer and dropdown form in Contact section (ignore all the missing content): English: [link](http://www.joshofsorts.com/projects/dsenergy/), Spanish [link](http://www.joshofsorts.com/projects/dsenergy/sp).

Comment: The string seems to be there, so the error is probably more on the javascript side: `var interest = "Área De Interés*:";`

Comment: @Marvin, that is what I am thinking too, just not sure why the javascript will only output the `else` version of `var interest`.

Comment: if you echo string to js variable need to wrap it in js quotes. look at the version browser receives, surely it's throwing error in console. If you use `json_encode` it actually would do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to my last comment: I am sure that there is a JavaScript error somewhere. The variable is correctly set if you inspect the source, so PHP works as intended.

Looking at the JavaScript console in Chrome, I see the following error message, which only appears for the Spanish version, thus making it an ideal candidate for further investigations:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined in jquery.easytabs.min.js?ver=3.2.0:12
```

Comment: That did it, I commented out the easytabs plugin and it works now. I was ignoring that being broken initially because I thought it was only breaking the tabs part of the page, didn't realize it could effect other things. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the bare bones if statement:

```
<?php 
  $the_page=1;

  if($the_page === 1) {
    echo "1: \$the_page=$the_page";
  }
  else{ 
    echo "else: \$the_page=$the_page";
  }
//echos "1: $the_page=1"
```

and then

```
<?php 
  $the_page=frenchfry;

  if($the_page === 1) {
    echo "1: \$the_page=$the_page";
  }
  else{ 
    echo "else: \$the_page=$the_page";
  }
//echoes else: $the_page=frenchfry
```

I would say the problem is with `is_page('sp')`; did you say you are able to echo it and verify it is a numeric `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition `if(is_page('sp'))` , this surely return `false` so your variable `$the_page` is not set to 1 so it always end up in your `else statement`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're closing your php tags on the statements, and so its running both because they are both in plain html. You only see the last one because it happens last.  Try this:

```
<?php if(is_page('sp')){$the_page = 1;} else { };

if($the_page === 1) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>".
        "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {".
            "$('#form-interest option:first:contains('---')').html('Área De Interés*:');".
        "});".
    "</script>";
<?php } else { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
        "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {".
            "$('#form-interest option:first:contains('---')').html('Area of Interest*:');".
        "});".
    "</script>";
    }
?>
```

You seem to be a bit confused on syntax, so hope that makes some sense.

Comment: `<?php } else {` needs to be just `} else {`, although the original syntax is already perfectly fine.

Comment: Am I missing something here with all these answers?  It looks to me like his php code is this:

<?php if(is_page('sp')){$the_page = 1;} else { };

if($the_page === 1) {}
} else {}
?>

And his html code is this:

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#form-interest option:first:contains('---')").html('Área De Interés*:');
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#form-interest option:first:contains('---')").html('Area of Interest*:');
        });
    </script>